# ASP.Net C#: Radio Button do not fire up OnCheckedChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to use RadioButton control to change sort in a ViewList control.

But my problem is OnCheckedChanged Event did not fire up.

I Google about this problem and do some works like set AutoPostBack as true or use RadioButtonList or wrap RadioButtons inside Update Panel. But the problem still persist.

**Edit 1: I added my codes.**

My *aspx* code:

```
<div class="col-6 text-right">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="sortNewest" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True"
                GroupName="QuestionSort" Text="Newest" OnCheckedChanged="sortQuestionRadioButton_OnCheckedChanged"/>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="sortVotes" AutoPostBack="True"
                GroupName="QuestionSort" Text="Votes" OnCheckedChanged="sortQuestionRadioButton_OnCheckedChanged"/>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="sortUnanswered" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True"
                GroupName="QuestionSort" Text="Unanswered" OnCheckedChanged="sortQuestionRadioButton_OnCheckedChanged" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My *Event* function:

```
protected void sortQuestionRadioButton_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton = (RadioButton) sender;
    QuestionSortValue.Value = radioButton.Text.ToLower();
    QuestionsList.DataBind();
}
```

**Edit 2: Note**
Problem is not related to Bootstrap, because I had tested it without any style but problem persisted.

**Edit 3: Note**
Problem es exactly related to Bootstrap `data-toggle` attribute. You can find correct answer from above link.

Comment: Share your code, particularly the method you have subscribed to the event and where you subscribe it.

Comment: I dont see a reason to down vote this question. Share your code and see if any one can help.

Comment: Share your code, just check it after to set AutoPostBack=true in radio button.

Comment: @schar Thanks. I will share my code as soon as possible because I replace them with a DropDown list and a button.

Comment: @SurajKumar as I say I have done that but it didn't work.

Comment: @SamW I shared my code.

Comment: @schar  I shared my code.

Comment: @anantjaiswal  I shared my code.

Comment: Does a post-back occur at all when you check a radio button? If not, have you checked the console for javascript errors? If so, have you checked with breakpoints if your `OnCheckedChange` event is hit? Where are you setting the `DataSource` for `QuestionsList` ? What is `QuestionSortValue` ?

Comment: @JonP There is no sign of any `PostBack`, Or JavaScript error or firing up event. I checked them last min ago as you say. I set data source with `SelectMethod` but it does not related to these radio buttons. I save `RadioButton`s value in a hidden element and use that data in `SelectMethod`

Comment: Probably not related, *but*, you have two buttons with `Checked="True"`, that doesn't really make sense with radio buttons

Comment: @JonP Thanks. It was for copy and paste. And It was solved. I finally found my answer in another post. I linked it to this post too. thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved.**
Excuse me, it was my fault.
When I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47721360/7672704) I got that it's related to Bootstrap toggle.

I'm so sorry. thanks for trying.